# How can I resolved syntax error in Moodle?

Tags: moodle

I have the Eguru theme installed in Moodle, but the images are not displayed. I get this error:

Excepción - Call to undefined function sibil@gmail.com()

error/moodle/generalexceptionmessage

What can I do?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: In Moodle, switch debug level to developer, what error message do you get? Site administration > Development > Debugging and then debug = developer and debugdisplay = on

Comment: Hi, Russell
My Moodle version is 3.7 
That email address is used by the admin user.
If I want to upgrade Eguru Theme, How can I?  What are the steps? I´m not developer. I would appreciate it if you could explain me in detail. 
About debugging procees I have questions: If I do it I would deconfigure the page?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: If you can switch on debugging please, and then try again it will display the line where the error is. Then copy and paste or take a screenshot and update this question. This will help developers to fix the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.